# Pass custom object as parameter to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new in ASP Net Core. I've made some basics CRUDs in an API Rest made in this Framework. Now I have to make a new endpoint which can receive 3 attributes or less. Att1, Attr2, Attr3. According to how I have worked so far, the controller has to receive as a parameter an object, but in this case, there is not an entity or DTO that it has this attribute. I made with a Dictionary, from this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters)
{
    var Respuesta =  _prLiquidacionesService.Liquidar(parameters);
    return Ok(Respuesta);
}
```

But I don't know if it's the best way to make it. Maybe is better to define a request entity called LiquidacionRequest and define the attributes that I need there?

Please could you give me your opinions?

Comment: There is a [`FromBody` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that might help when being attached to your `parameters` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

You can use model binding with a `Dictionary`, just make your query string in the following format:

#### From Query

```
https://Example.com/Controller/Action?parameters[key]=value1&parameters[key2]=value2&parameters[key3]=value3
```

#### From Body

To be honest i couldn't make it work with a `Dictionary` without a custom model binder but there is a proper replacement which is `List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>` that can expose a similar API.

Json data sample:

```json
[
    {
        "Key": "asd",
        "Value": 123
    },
    {
        "Key": "dsa",
        "Value": 321
    }
]
```

Action:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>> parameters)
{
    var Respuesta =  _prLiquidacionesService.Liquidar(parameters);
    return Ok(Respuesta);
}
```

If your method requires a `Dictionary` then a simple cast would do the job:

```cs
parameters.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

See the documentation for more examples.
[MSDN Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#dictionaries)

Comment: what are the benefits of passing parameters via query string rather then body?

Comment: @ЯрославВиталиевич It's a matter of choice and how the action is configured to receive information, i just provided an example via query string because op said that the action will receive 3 attributes or less. I usually go with body for more complex data.

Comment: Thanks, for your explanation. IMO, passing params via query has several drawbacks, that's why I asked. 1) Query has a limited size, 2) Query params is insecure as it is stored in browser history. 3) Query is primarily using rather for filtering then for passing data.

Comment: Yes, the idea is pass parameters via body.

Comment: @user2048789 Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try. this way